# How to deal with buffering when using pipes to connect to a console program

Tags: c, winapi

I have a win32 program (yes, I'm stuck using win32) that launches a child process and connects to its stdin/stdout through anonymous pipes.  Most of the time I do not own the child process (hence, I don't have access to the code).  I'm finding that the child's stdout buffering is getting in the way.  I don't see any output from the child until I terminate the process; however, I do know that input is processed as it is received.

So, I've read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351/en-us, which warns of the problem with child process's use of printf (etc) regarding buffering, and microsoft's *brilliant* fix for this is to follow all printfs in the child with fflush() (a simpler way would be to just use setbuf(stdout,0); however that assumes you have access to the child source code).

Apparently a child process doesn't flush stdout when it is attached to a parent's pipe. Is there a way around this without needing to modify the child?

I have verified this using a simple child:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    char line[256];

    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
            char *lp;

    //      setbuf(stdout,0);
            while(1) {
                    printf("Prompt:");
                    lp = gets(line);
                    printf("Got: <%s>\n",lp);
                    if (strcmp(lp,"yada") == 0) {
                            int fd = open("C:/tmp/yada123",O_BINARY|O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
                            if (fd > 0) {
                                    write (fd,"hi!\n",4);
                                    close(fd);
                            }
                    }
                    if (strcmp(lp,"exit") == 0) {
                            printf("bye!\n");
                            break;
                    }
            }
}
```

If I uncomment the setbuf() call at the top, then interaction is clean; however note that I don't typically have the option to modify the child code.  Also, I verified that the other direction is not buffered (even though I don't see output); because the file is written when  the string "yada" is received.

Comment: I would suggest you search out ways to inject code into another process under win32.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean here...

Comment: google "windows remote code injection" and you will learn about ways to define a thread in your executable (the one you have source for) that gets run by another executable (the one you lack source for). You'll want to design a thread that sets the buffering you want and give that thread to the child to run.

Comment: There are several ways to inject code into another process. Most of them use a dll injection. A dll can have a dll main function, which gets called while loading the dll. In this function you would simply do `setbuf(stdout,0);`. All you need now is to get the child process to load your dll. So search for a dll injection.

Comment: I'll look into this (never heard of remote code injection); but to be clear, I own the parent (the executable that will launch the program that I don't have the code for).  The above code snippet is an example that demonstrates the problem with the child that I would typically not have control of.  With buffering on, the parent (not shown) does not see the child's output; with buffering off it works fine. If that wasn't clear, I apologize.

Comment: You need the child to do unbuffered IO. One possible solution is to force the child to call `setbuf(stdout,0);` (without knowing or either changing the code of the child). You can do this by code injection.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't see this response... Ok, I'm trying to get my head around this "code injection" stuff.  Tried implementing something based on a few articles online...(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces#section_3), no luck so far.  Does this *really* allow me to insert a line (thread) of code into a running process?

Answer (score 0):

Foreword: In the comments of the question was outlined, that code injection might solve the problem. This post shows one possible implementation of a dll injection and therefore supplement the comments. I post the code as normal post, to get a better presentation of multiple lines of code.

The following code might be a good starting point for a dll injection. It uses a global hook. This is a very simple method, but it injects your dll into ALL running process (only into those you have the permission for). So you must ask for the current program name and call `setbuf(stdout,0);` only in the case you are in the desired application :-)
Maybe You need to add some header files (I only some code fragments together and did not test it).

The `void InstallHook(void)` and `void RemoveHook(void)` function must be declared as dll export functions, so either you are using a *.def file or declare them as `__declspec( dllexport )`. This might depend on your compiler and your settings.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);

  switch (ul_reason_for_call)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  {
    wchar_t buffer [1024];
    // get the path and executable name of the current process
    GetModuleFileNameW( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), buffer, 1024 );
    //test if we are in the target app
    if ( _wcsicmp( buffer, "C:/some_dir/some_app.exe" ) == 0 )
    {
      setbuf(stdout,0);
    }
    break;
  }
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }

  return (true);
}

HHOOK gl_hHook = NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  return (CallNextHookEx( gl_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

// call this function before or after you have started the child process
// the hook gets installed and your dll is loaded into each running process
// and the DllMain functions gets called by each process
void InstallHook(void)
{
  gl_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, HookProc, gl_hThisInstance, 0 );
}

void RemoveHook(void)
{
  UnhookWindowsHookEx( gl_hHook );
}
```